# Marriage with baby's feeder

Tags: nikah, shiism

I have question in Shia's law. If a woman feeding baby through her breasts in enough time and enough amount, *can father of the baby marry with her?*

Answer (score 1):

In the name Allah, the Entirely merciful, the Especially Merciful / **بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم**

---

Based on my research/conclusion –if I’m not mistaken--, if we consider the mentioned woman as foster-mother (Rada/redaee (figh) mother) and likewise by supposing that all the conditions of Radaee mother have been done properly/entirely, subsequently it can be concluded that:

**She can get married to baby's father.**

Since based on what I've perceived in the issue of Rada (fiqh), such feeding (of milk...) doesn't make the Radaee-mother mahram to baby's father, hence she (foster mother) can get married to baby's father.

Hopefully, I've concluded it properly. Good luck.

---

**References:**

[article.tebyan.net/5713](https://article.tebyan.net/5713/%D8%A8%D8%A7-%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%88-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C-%D9%86%D9%85%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%AF-) & etc.

www.sistani.org/persian/book/50/116/

www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/4345

www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa12832

www.farsnews.com/printable.php?nn=13901201001519